# How do raising bases to exponents work?(Basic NumberTheory Question)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have a question here that, because I don't understand a part of it, I don't have any work. Sorry.

"Let $B$ be a base that is greater than $50^{50}$, and let $N = (11_B)^{50}$. Let $X$ be the third digit (from the right) of $N$ when expressed in base $B$. Express $X$ as a base-10 number."

I'm kind of confused here. Since B is a base greater than $50^{50}$, doesn't that mean that x would be 0, as well as any number besides the right-most term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that $11_B=B+1$, so

$$N=(B+1)^{50}=\sum_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}kB^k\tag{1}$$

by the binomial theorem. For $k=0,\ldots,50$ we have

$$\binom{50}k=\frac{50!}{k!(50-k)!}<50!<50^{50}<B\;,$$

so the numbers $\binom{50}k$ are possible digits in base $B$, and the base $B$ representation of $N$ is therefore

$$(d_{50}d_{49}\ldots d_0)_B\;,$$

where $d_k$, the coefficient of $B^k$ in the representation of $N$ as a sum of distinct powers of $B$, is given by $$d_k=\binom{50}k\;.$$ In particular, $d_2$, the coefficient of $B^2$, is the third digit from the right, and it’s $\dbinom{50}2=1225$ when expressed as a base ten number.